# Detecting NFC on android devices

Tags: android, nfc

Well, my purpose is to detect if the Android device supports NFC and if not I will use some other technology. I have set my minimum API level to 8 as I want my app to function even on these devices without NFC.

Is there a method like isNFCSupported()? any ideas?

thanks
yosoh.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Step #1: Put this in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
```

Step #2: Call [`hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29) on `PackageManager` to see if NFC is available on the current device

Comment: You might also want to check if NFC is actually turned on

Comment: @Thomas do you know how to check if it is turned on?

Comment: Will hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)  just check whether NFC is supported or not???

Comment: @RohanLodhi: The one-parameter `hasSystemFeature()` has existed on `PackageManager` since Android 2.0. See [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29).