# Checking NFC feature on Android Device

Tags: android, android-emulator, nfc, android-virtual-device

This is in response to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805034/detecting-nfc-on-android-devices)

```
Step #1: Put this in your manifest:

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
Step #2: Call hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC) on PackageManager to see if NFC is available on the current device
```

i set the API level to 8,Step 1 is ok, but when I write `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)` it says `Feature_NFC` doesnot resolve to a field,`Feature_WIFI FEATURE_BLUETOOTH FEATURE_CAMERA` are the options there.
I have visited [Android developer Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_NFC),but they didn't mention the API level.
Another question is Can I test NFC application on AVD?
Anyone who can help me this
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are setting project build target to at least api level 9.

Include folliwng in manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" /> //If you have icecream sandwich installed.
```

It will ensure that your application will be runnable on sdk 8 also

Also make sure whenever you are calling Gingerbread specific features then wrap them into if condition
as follows.

```
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {

    } else {
        if (getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)) {
            //do processing
        }
    }
```

For testing You can give a try to [Open NFC Android emulator](http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/)

Comment: in the above code where are you getting Feature.NFC? moreover can i use NFC app in AVD?\

Comment: what project build target you are setting?

Answer (score 0):

FEATURE_NFC is defined from API Level 9, but you can still use the constant value "android.hardware.nfc".

Comment: where we have to call the hasSystemFeature(string)? inside main activty?

Comment: yes call getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC) in onCreate

Comment: Never tried any but there is Open NFC Android emulator.I have shared a link in answer try it.