# Android, combine application components of different SDK versions

Tags: android, plugins, android-intent, android-activity, target

I am looking for an approach, how to combine components of different SDK versions.

For example, I have an APP that works fine with minSdkVersion="8".
But I would like to have an additional feature, that require minSdkVersion="10".

Maybe something like a plugin and load it dynamicaly? If the android device has minSdkVersion="10" it would load that plugin. And by lower versions it would just work with basic functionality with SdkVersion="8".

Is there any approach for that? May be create two activities in different package and load one activity from intent as interface? any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess you could use ``Build.VERSION`` to disguise between different API levels your app is running on. Then act accordingly on code level using if-elses.

Comment: The problem is, that in a manifest file I need to specify minSdkVersion. If I want to build in a component been supported from minSdkVersion=10 I am not able to compile the package with minSdkVersion=8. So I would like to load additional component dynamicaly... somehow :)

Comment: I'm afraid that only way is to compile against highest API you're using and make sure that none of the higher level API calls get called on lower APIs.

Comment: but in "normal" I could use interfaces for building "plugins"... nothing similar in android?

Comment: Yes, you can use Java interfaces but I think you can't load libraries dynamically to make distinction between API versions. I might be wrong on this one though. And if this is the case you should make sure that your factory methods check against current API level and create implementation classes accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

To target multiple platforms, you specify a minimum SDK level, and a target SDK level when building the project. You configure the project to link against the target SDK build. The Davlik VM will generate runtime exceptions if you ever execute a call against a method that's not present on the current platform. The compiler will generate warnings for calls that not available on the minimum SDK level. There are various Java @ declarations that suppress those warnings on classes, methods, or particular references. Press the F2 key in Eclipse to auto-generate the Java decoration that's appropriate. It sounds intimidating. But in practice, the warnings allow you to code relatively fearlessly.

So the general approach is: link against the target SDK libraries; add @ decorations to code that uses methods from higher SDK builds; decorate the methods or classes that are specific to a particular build; and live and die by the "all warnings are errors" rule of coding.

Re-implementing an entire activity for each API level is overkill. Class specialization with overriden methods is not a happy way to do this kind of thing. The binding complexity makes it difficult to work this way. Far better to use a smaller helper class or conditional code.

There are various conventions on writing Helper classes -- essentially a separate implementation class for each API level, each implementing a common interface or abstract base class. The method given in the Android developer blog, is a reasonably tidy way to do it. There are plenty of minor variation on the pattern, all based on obtaining an instance of a helper class for a particular API level.

Another example of this pattern would be the IActionBarHelper interface used in the google ActionBarCompat libary. In that case, your Activities inherit from ActivityCompat, instead of Activity, and the instance method ActivityCompat.getActionBarHelper() returns an implementation of IActionBarHelper that provides an appropriate implementation for the platform you're running on. In this case, the implementations contain a fair bit of initialization state, and state associated with the activity; so it makes sense to obtain the implementation from a member method.

Despite all that, the Davlik VM is perfectly capable of dealing with inline methods that don't have linkage.

```
  if (Build.Version >= 10) { 
      Call an API 10 method.
  }
```

also works perfectly well. The Davlik VM does whine a little bit via debug messages in LogCat. So there might be some overhead if you were to do this all the time. If you were to execute the API-10 method on a downlevel platform, the Davlik loader generates code that throws a runtime exception when executed instead of executing the call. But the code links and loads fine. The if statement is all you need to prevent execution of the missing method. In small doses, conditional code is perfectly ok. If there's a lot of platform-specific code, it's probably better to encapsulate platform-specific functionaily in a class, somehow.

For features which are either there, or not there, like your NFC example, the best way to proceed is probably to implement as much of the NFC functionality in a class; and then conditionally reference that class from code in your main class or activity. e.g.:

```
 void onCreate(...)
 {
    if (Build.Version >= 10) 
    {
         mNfcReceiver = new NfcReceiver(getContext());
    }
 }
```

The Helper class pattern doesn't really help you much, since you're obviously not going to reimplement the functionality on downlevel platforms.

Comment: Thanks all for answers.. I was able to solve this issue using @ decoration in eclipse: @SuppressLint("NewApi"). And then I checked if for something like:
if(Build.Version >= 10){
load NFC class extends Basic class
} else {
load Basic class
}

Answer (score 1):

And, if you use support libraries?

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

What kind of features  needed?

Comment: NFC adapater.. it is supported from sdkversion=10. My app is build at sdkversion=8.. and this NFC-plugin should we just an additional feature for the App. So it's pity to increase sdkversion and lose users only because of a "plugin"..

Comment: Maybe this post helps you,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070492/checking-nfc-feature-on-android-device If you use the sdk 10 but you set the minSDK in 8

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is very detailed explained on the Android Developers Official blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html

It's basically applying Java Lazy loading, which is a programming pattern that takes advantage on the fact that Java only loads a class whenever it's first called.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for answers.. I was able to solve this issue using @ decoration in eclipse: @SuppressLint("NewApi").

In my parent activity I just checked for the VERSION and NFC Support and write to this.supportNFC; after that I select which intent to load

```
if(this.supportNFC == KITAPP.NFC_ENABLED){
   intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNFC.class);
} else {
   intent = new Intent(this, ActivityBasic.class);
}
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

btw,

```
class ActivityNFC extends ActivityBasic{}
```

so I just extended my NFC-class with additional features for NFC. But if the mobile device does not support NFC or has lower Verion, it would load basic features.